# Java Reactor onComplete inconsistency

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm sure that I'm just missing something. I'm running the following code:

```
@Test
public void simpleCreation() throws Exception {
    Iterator<String> data = ImmutableList.of("1", "2", "3").iterator();
    Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.create(emmiter -> {
        while ( data.hasNext() ) {
            emmiter.next(data.next());
        }
        emmiter.complete();
    });
    ConnectableFlux<String> connectableFlux = stringFlux.publish();

    connectableFlux.doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("connectableFlux.doOnComplete"));
    stringFlux.doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("stringFlux.doOnComplete"));

    CountDownLatch completeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Disposable disposable = connectableFlux.subscribe(s -> {
        System.out.println("subscribe: data: " + s);
    }, error -> { }, completeLatch::countDown);

    connectableFlux.connect();

    completeLatch.await();
    disposable.dispose();
}
```

and expect it to print either "connectableFlux.doOnComplete" or "stringFlux.doOnComplete" or both, but I see neither. OnComplete callback from subscribe method is executed with no problem, but neither of these methods called and I do not quite see why.

For me it looks slightly inconsistent - in one place callback is called and others are just ignored. I can observe the similar behaviour with doOnNext.

I would appreciate if someone can explain the concept behind that. I'm sure that is not bug, but just something I'm missing about the framework or the concept in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is causing the problem:

```
connectableFlux.doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("connectableFlux.doOnComplete"));
```

The result of the call to `doOnComplete()` is ignored. The method returns a new version of the Flux instance on which you want to call `subscribe()`, it does not add the logic to the old `connectableFlux` instance.

Try it like this:

```
Iterator<String> data = ImmutableList.of("1", "2", "3").iterator();
Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.create(emmiter -> {
    while (data.hasNext()) {
        emmiter.next(data.next());
    }
    emmiter.complete();
});

stringFlux.doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("stringFlux.doOnComplete()"))
        .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("subscribe: data: " + s), error -> {})
        .dispose();

stringFlux.publish().connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't add this as a comment, so sorry about bumping an old question. Just wanted to share this bit of the official Reactor guide:

> B.2. I used an operator on my Flux but it doesn’t seem to apply. What gives?
>   Make sure that the variable you .subscribe() to has been affected by the operators you think should have been applied to it.
>
> Reactor operators are decorators. They return a different instance that wraps the source sequence and add behavior. That is why the preferred way of using operators is to chain the calls.
>
> Compare the following two examples:
>
> without chaining (incorrect)

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.just("foo", "chain");
flux.map(secret -> secret.replaceAll(".", "*")); 
flux.subscribe(next -> System.out.println("Received: " + next));
The mistake is here. The result isn’t attached to the flux variable.
```

> without chaining (correct)

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.just("foo", "chain");
flux = flux.map(secret -> secret.replaceAll(".", "*"));
flux.subscribe(next -> System.out.println("Received: " + next));
```

> This sample is even better (because it’s simpler):
>
> with chaining (best)

```
Flux<String> secrets = Flux
  .just("foo", "chain")
  .map(secret -> secret.replaceAll(".", "*"))
  .subscribe(next -> System.out.println("Received: " + next));
```

> The first version will output:

```
Received: foo
Received: chain
```

> Whereas the two other versions will output the expected:

```
Received: ***
Received: *****
```

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.chain